# Curl command working on mobile but not in desktop

Tags: curl, openssl

I think the problem is in my openssl library but i need to know wich is the problem to solve it.

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.14
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

When i use this curl command:

```
curl -k -vv \
--header 'ModuleID: 12' \
--header 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/ILogInService/AreUserAndPasswordCorrect' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8' \
--data '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:AreUserAndPasswordCorrect>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:userName>a</tem:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:password>b</tem:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:extension>0</tem:extension>
      </tem:AreUserAndPasswordCorrect>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>' https://212.121.254.90:7777/Services/LogInService.svc
```

I get this response:

```
*   Trying 212.121.254.90:7777...
* Connected to 212.121.254.90 (212.121.254.90) port 7777 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Conexión reinicializada por la máquina remota in connection to 212.121.254.90:7777 
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Conexión reinicializada por la máquina remota in connection to 212.121.254.90:7777
```

But the same cURL command on my mobile returns:
[image]

I think it has something to do with the openssl version, the mobile is using BoringSSL, and one server from Amazon that works too is using openssl 1.1.1

How can i make it work in an actual openssl implementation? or how can i confirm wich is the problem?

Comment: Do 'desktop' and 'mobile' use the same Internet connection? (I assume 'Amazon' doesn't.) If not look for things on desktop network like WAF IDS/IPS DLP and try to share connections from one to the other (i.e. have desktop use hotspot from mobile and/or have mobile use hotspot from desktop).

Comment: They are on the same WiFi